# Specify Saved Image Dimensions in Seabron FacetGrid

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn, figure

I cannot override the Seaborn defaults on image size.

I would think that the `plt.figure(figsize=(8.5,11))` would specify the actual dimensions of the image saved. It does not. The dimensions of the saved file are 4.5" by 2.25". That is different from 8.5" x 11".

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8.5,11))

df = sb.load_dataset('tips')
g = sb.FacetGrid(df, col = "time")
g.map(plt.hist, "tip")
plt.savefig("size_test_plot.jpg")
plt.show()
```

What is the solution?

Comment: @Bazingaa?  Seems you might know :)

Comment: I think the duplicates answers your question

Comment: @Bazingaa - yes, the g.fig.set_size_inches(15,15). A bit buried, hadn't found it yet. THanks!